# How do I have a function find two elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner with JavaScript so I'm sure this will be an elementary question.

With this function below, I want it to find the two elements and add them to a header element. Right now, the only thing that is working is the element, the link with the rel:author tag. I'm sure this is probably a syntax thing.

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".single .single-post-module").each(function() {
      $(this).find('a[rel="author"]', 'span[class="updated"]').clone().appendTo($(this).find('.post-header h1'));
      //            ^^^
    });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

Edit: I'm using Divi on wordpress and the site is in maintenance mode. That's why didn't show the HTML or give a link.

Comment: Please do not use syntax to highlight parts of code. Indicate with a comment.

Comment: [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) expects a CSS selector. Make a CSS selector that matches two elements, and not two selectors that match one element each -> `'a[rel="author"], span[class="updated"]'`

Comment: Without your html we can’t really offer sensible advice.

Comment: try using `.find('a[rel="author"], span[class="updated"]')` with a single string as an argument and the comma being within the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with pure Javscript `querySelectorAll` with an CSS selector that will find both elements.

To clone the element, use [`cloneNode(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) where the first parameter indicates to clone 'deep'

```js
const header = document.querySelector('.post-header > h1');

const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.single, .single-post-module');
Array.from(elements).forEach(e => header.append(e.cloneNode(true)));
```

```html
<div class='single'>
    <a rel='author'>Link</a>
    <span class='updated'>Span</span>
</div>

<div class='single-post-module'>
    <a rel='author'>Link</a>
    <span class='updated'>Span</span>
</div>

<div class='post-header'>
  <h1></h1>
</div>
```